# I can't update my db records with laravel authenticated user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm a newbie at Laravel and I'm trying to make an update to the database via the authenticated user but the DB doesn't reflect any updates. But when I specify a user ID, DB updates just fine. But I need the authenticated user to be able to make updates. See code below with comments. I'm using laravel 7 please.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserController extends Controller {
    
    public function uploadAvatar(Request $request)
    {
       if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $filename = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->image->storeAs('images', $filename, 'public');
            
            auth()->user()->update(['image' => $filename]);   //no updates made with this code
            //User::find(2)->update(['image' => $filename]); //this works fine
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }  
    return view('welcome');
}
}
```

This is my route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
Route::post('/upload', 'UserController@uploadAvatar');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .. chec in user model fillable property https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: I've done that. Image is set to "fillable". Still don't know what to do.

Comment: can you upload your route? code

Comment: Is the user authenticated in the request?

Comment: Is there code missing? Too many `}`. `$request->hasFile('image')` does your request have an image?

Comment: My route is uploaded

Comment: Yes my request has an image. The upload goes into local storage i.e storage/public/images but does not reflect in the DB.

Comment: But when I specify user ID before uploading as in code above, the DB gets updated.

Comment: Do you get any error like call to member function update on null or anything else